# Assets not sent after issuing successful trade transaction on Serum DEX

Tags: dex, serum

We deployed the Serum UI and DEX contract and managed to create orders but for some reason, when trade happens, assets are not sent to seller/buyer.

Comment: it's not clear to me that you've fully issued transactions such that a trade is executed.  can you fully elaborate the instructions issued to create the market and "complete" the trade?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

After a trade occurs on Serum it's necessary to send another transaction to settle the funds. See the Serum FAQ here: https://docs.projectserum.com/serum-ecosystem/help#why-cant-i-see-my-tokens-in-my-wallet-after-a-trade

Comment: Thanks I settled the fund but the token never leave whoever created the order. 
For example:
A create Buy Order at 1 token for 99 USDC
then B create Sell Order at 99USCD for 1 token

The 1 token sent to A but 99 USDC stay in the contract and B not receive 99 USDC

Comment: Rather than answering right away, I recommend asking the person who posted the question for more information. What exactly did they try, what did they expect and why, and what was the result they observed. With as much detail as possible. Otherwise any answer is guesswork.